# javax.mail.MessagingException could not connect to SMTP host port :25 response -1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, testng

I am getting a response code of -1 and I am not sure what is the workaround for this. The office has a firewall setting which cannot be disabled as well as antivirus running.Since the `java` code is running from the office,how do I get this code working to email the testing report.

```
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@540408: 16 ms
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.5
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.5
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "xxx.com", port 25, isSSL false
DEBUG SMTP: EOF: [EOF]
DEBUG SMTP: could not connect to host "xxxx.com", port: 25, response: -1

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: xxx.com, port: 25, response: -1
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1960)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.seleniumtests.test.SendFileEmail.trySendEmail(SendFileEmail.java:131)
    at com.seleniumtests.test.Email.generateReport(Email.java:27)
    at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:1094)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1053)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Code to send the email:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT );
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication("myusername","mypassword");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you connect to the same mailserver by entering `telnet xxx.com 25` from a command prompt?

Comment: Hi, since administrator rights are disabled I could not do that .

Comment: In that case, are your double, triple sure you can connect to port 25 of that given mail server?

Comment: Hi, since administrator rights are disabled I could not do that .I got the name of the mail server used in the host by going to Microsoft Outlook-> Options->Mail Setup-> Email Accounts-> Edit the account ,which gives the server name.Is there any other way to find what the "host" need to be set to?

Comment: Does your mailserver require authentication? If so, did you supply that?

Comment: Yes it does .this is code which I am using: 
      Properties props = new Properties();   
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);  
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
      props.put("mail.debug", "true");  
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT );        

      Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator()  
        {protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication   
            getPasswordAuthentication()   
        {return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication("myusername","mypassword");}});

Answer (score 1):

From the [Java Mail API FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#connectsend):

> You should call `trans.sendMessage(msg, addrs)` to send the message. As described above, the `send` method is a static convenience method that acquires its own `Transport` object and creates its own connection to use for sending; it does not use the connection associated with any `Transport` object through which it is invoked.

In short, don't call `Transport.send(...)`, call `Transport.sendMessage(...)` instead.